# selenium failed to reload page with python

Tags: python, selenium

The reason I am trying to do this is because sometimes if the network is not good, then the loading/refreshing will eventually hang and so I have this idea to at first set a timeout for the chromedriver, then try to catch the exception when the timeout is reached and re-load again.

it's simple code, I am trying to integrate the timeout catch feature into the selenium. 
It seems the chrome will never really re-load. Even when I changed the timeout to 100 second in the load_page function( which is not in the current code.)

Is it a bug of the chrome driver? Why is it not reloading?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep


def load_page(func, arg, driver):
    load_retry = 0
    while 1:
        if load_retry > 3:
            return False
        try:
            func(arg)
            print('load success!')
            return True
        except TimeoutException:
            load_retry += 1
            print('retrying')

            try:
                driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
            except TimeoutException:
                sleep(2)
                continue




chrome = os.path.join('../resources/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=chrome)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

url = 'http://tieba.baidu.com/f?ie=utf-8&kw=c%2B%2B&fr=search&red_tag=f1842571998'

load_page(driver.get, url, driver)

driver.quit()
```

update:
I actually did a own re-work with the webdriver.Chrome, basically I just run driver.quit() if I catch the exception, then in next loop start a new  webdriver.Chrome instance again.

It is ugly I think, but it did work.

Comment: Why should the page reload with this code? This code only tries to open an URL. Could you post the output you get from this program and exactly what the expected behavior is?

Comment: @Metareven I am trying to test the timeout then retry block here. So I set a very slow website to test, in my case, the page cannot load in most casese within 5 seconds. Then I tried to foce pause the loading, the reload. But it seems the chromedriver will not behave as I wanted it to be

Comment: Have you tried using driver.refresh() instead of navigating to the same page you are already on? I am not 100% sure how this is implemented in chromedriver, but it could be that trying to navigate to the page that you are already on basically does nothing.

Again it would be nice if you could post the output of this code

Comment: @Metareven Hi, I did try the refresh method. It seems, this method will work if the page has already been load completely. If the page is not completetly loaded then paused, then refresh method will not work.

Comment: @bot1 Can you update the question with the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: @DebanjanB Hi, I upated. actually I found a own solution, but not very beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I did a rework for the webdriver.Chrome to make a more robust reload and refresh behavior. Feel free to take it.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep


class BetterChrome(webdriver.Chrome):
    default_timeout = 10
    better_setting = {
        'options': '', 'path':''
    }
    def set_better_setting(self, options, path):
        BetterChrome.better_setting['options'] = options
        BetterChrome.better_setting['path'] = path
        self.set_page_load_timeout(BetterChrome.default_timeout)

    def better_refresh(self):
        return self.better_load_page(self.current_url)


    def better_load_page(self, url):
        load_retry = 0
        timeout = BetterChrome.default_timeout
        default_setting = BetterChrome.better_setting
        while 1:
            print('retrying')
            if load_retry > 8:
                return False, False
            try:
                self.get(url)
                print('load success!')
                self.set_better_setting(default_setting['options'], default_setting['path'])
                return True, self
            except TimeoutException:
                load_retry += 1
                # print('retrying')
                self.quit()

                self = BetterChrome(chrome_options=default_setting['options'], executable_path=default_setting['path'])
                self.maximize_window()
                timeout += 15
                self.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)

chrome = os.path.join('../resources/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = BetterChrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path = chrome)
driver.set_better_setting(options, chrome)
url = 'https://www.google.de'
status, driver = driver.better_load_page(url)
if status:
    driver.quit()
```